# sabre: looping through TEL-property doesn´t provide what expected

Tags: php, vcf-vcard, sabre, sabredav

A probably simple question - but I´m blockheaded:

Following [sabre/vobject usage instruction](http://sabre.io/vobject/vcard/) I will loop the TEL-property to get numbers and their types.

```
BEGIN:VCARD
TEL;TYPE=HOME,PREF:+15551234560
TEL;TYPE=HOME,FAX:+15551234569
TEL;TYPE=WORK:+155523456789
END:VCARD
```

```
foreach ($vCard->TEL as $number) {
    echo (string)$number . ': ' . $vCard->TEL['TYPE'] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Instead of

```
+15551234560: HOME,PREF
+15551234569: HOME,FAX
+155523456789: WORK
```

I receive:

```
+15551234560: HOME,PREF
+15551234569: HOME,PREF
+155523456789: HOME,PREF
```

Comment: Can you try this

foreach ($vCard->TEL as $key => $number) {
    echo (string)$number . ': ' . $vCard[$key]['TYPE'] . PHP_EOL;
}

note: not tested, just a suggestion

Comment: @ImranMomin what difference will it make? Adding a key doesn’t seems to solve a problem here

Comment: "Adding a key doesn’t seems to solve a problem here " - that´s true!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is:

```
foreach ($vCard->TEL as $key => $number) {
    echo (string)$number . ': ' . $vCard->TEL[$key]->parameters['TYPE'] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($vCard->TEL as $number) {
    echo (string)$number . ': ' . $number['TYPE'] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: would you like to explain why this works and what changes you made?

Comment: Also, are you sure that `$number` is a string and an array too?

Comment: Result: "Illegal string offset 'TYPE'"